# iOS prepare to change to parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I'm trying to have a piece of code execute when my view controller is being dismissed (when the back button of the navigation controller is being tapped, opening the parent view controller). I have tried `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` and `viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` but neither have worked (or are even being called).

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[[AppDelegate fileDirectory]exitFolder].title);
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if ([self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[[AppDelegate fileDirectory]exitFolder].title);
    }
}
```

Comment: prepareForSegue is only called if you trigger a segue, the back-button is not a segue. regarding viewWillDisappear: is the view on-screen that you want the method to get called on?

Comment: viewWillDisappear should be called if the view controller is pushed onto the stack (via push segue), are you sure that the correct class is assigned to the view controller?

Comment: @mpolednik : The view controller is setup to the correct class. And I was hoping for a method that's called when a view controller is taken off of the stack via the back button.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the correct methods, but instead of `[self isMovingToParentViewController]` it should be `[self isMovingFromParentViewController]` in the if-statements

Answer (score 0):

can't you just execute your ***"piece of code"*** in **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidAppear** of your parentViewController?